# Which method works to determine the degrees of $\operatorname{arccot}(\tan(-37^\circ))$

Tags: trigonometry

Here, I want to convert $\tan(x)$ (let's say $\tan(-37^\circ)=\tan(x)$) to $\cot(x)$. Now, there is one identity$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}\pm x)=\mp\cot(x).$$If I choose $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+x)$ I will get $\cot(x),$ [$90^\circ +(-37^\circ))=\tan(90-37^\circ)=\cot(37^\circ)$] in the other way around $-\cot(x).$ So, which one must I choose to get the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\operatorname{arccot}(\tan(-37^\circ))=y\implies0<y<180^\circ\  \ \  \ (1)$ (See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values))

$$\implies\cot y=\tan(-37^\circ)=\cot(90^\circ+37^\circ)$$

$$\implies y=m180^\circ+90^\circ+37^\circ$$ where $m$ is an integer such that $(1)$ is satisfied.

Comment: thanks! But I think That here we don't need "m180" since it already satisfies (90+37=127) arccotangent's range of principal values 0° < y < 180°.

Comment: @Tug'tekin, That's by chance. You can safely this method for angle

Comment: I looked at the back of the book the to see the exact answer and it was 127 degrees! I suppose, in your sentence above you meant "You can USE safely this method for ANY angle".

Comment: @Tug'tekin, True

Comment: But what if one writes cot(y)=tan(-37)=cot(90-37), (according to the identity I have written above) so y=53 since it also satisfies 0° < y < 180°?

Comment: @Tug'tekin, $$\tan(-y)=-\tan y$$  and $$\tan y=\cot(90^\circ-y)$$